# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'radalert': object is null or undefined IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, asp.net-ajax, client-side-scripting

I am calling a RadAlert through server side Java Script in code behind file of an ASP.NET application. This RadAlert is working fine with IE7, IE9, Chrome and Firefox but IE8 throwing exception of 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'radalert': object is null or undefined'. Could please anyone tell me how I can resolve this issue.
Following is the code

```
string dialogMessage = "Record " + Session["SavedRecordID"].ToString() + " Saved Successfully";
string radalertscript = "<script language='javascript'> window.onload = function() {var oWnd = radalert('" + dialogMessage + "', 400, 140, 'Saved'); window.setTimeout(function () { oWnd.Close(); }, 3000);} </script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "radalert", radalertscript);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this on your local, or in an application you deployed?

Comment: it is on my local machine

Comment: OK, it's quite possible that you will experience this on all of the browsers when you deploy, because it could be a timing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the building up of the radalert object is happening too late in IE 8.  Since ASP.NET AJAX components use possibly a different lifecycle, you could also try (at least to eliminate whether what I'm saying is the actual problem):

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function(sender, e) {
  var oWnd = radalert('" + dialogMessage + "', 400, 140, 'Saved');
  window.setTimeout(function () { oWnd.Close(); }, 3000);}
});
```

You should be able to render this from the server and it function the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Brian. I have tried this approach but getting the same error. It is on my local machine.

Comment: Hmmm... do you have a RadWindowManager on the page or in the master page?  if you look through the scripts that have loaded in the visual studio debugger, do you see the script for the radalert?  The reasons for this occurring are either: 1) something caused the component creation to fail, like an error on the page or 2) the code using radalert is loading before the radalert definition gets loaded.

Comment: I have got your code working. For other's, just to let all of you know there is one extra curly bracket which goes completly un-noticed while working with code behind java script so just remove one before the end of Brian's code. Thank you very much Brian.